# Fluent NHibernate: Index was out of range exception with ReferencesAny mapping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to add a new record to database via creating a new object :

```
using (var session = conn.OpenNewSession())
{
 using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
 {
  TableHours hours = new TableHours(periodId, level, levelId.ToString(), levelTblRef);
  hours.WorkHours = 10;
  session.SaveOrUpdate(hours);
  tran.Commit(); //Exception thrown here
 }
}
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown after transaction.Commit() : "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

The error as I understand happens because of complicated mapping:

```
public class TableHours
{
public virtual int SaleMonthId { get; protected set; }
public virtual int Level { get; protected set; }
public virtual string LevelId { get; protected set; }
public virtual Level Lvl { get; protected set; }
public virtual decimal WorkHours { get; set; }
//..other methods
public TableHours(int saleMonthId, int level, string levelId, Level lvl)
{
            this.SaleMonthId = saleMonthId;
            this.Level = level;
            this.LevelId = levelId;
            this.Lvl = lvl;
}
}
```

And the mapping:

```
public class TableHoursMap : ClassMap<TableHours>
{
    public TableHoursMap()
    {
        Table("TableHours");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.SaleMonthId)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Level)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.LevelId, "Id");

        Map(x => x.SaleMonthId);

        Map(x => x.Level);

        Map(x => x.LevelId, "Id");

        Map(x => x.WorkHours);

        ReferencesAny(x => x.Lvl)
            .IdentityType<string>()
            .EntityTypeColumn("Level")
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("Id")
            .AddMetaValue<Level5>("5")
            .AddMetaValue<Level4>("4")
            .Not.Insert()
            .Not.Update()
            .Cascade.None()
            .ReadOnly();
}
}
```

I.e. Lvl field reference to table Level4 or Level5 table depending on Level value (4 or 5).
The select works perfect.
But when I'm trying to SaveOrUpdate I have the error above.

And small note. Without next attributes:

```
.Not.Insert()
.Not.Update()
.Cascade.None()
.ReadOnly();
```

I have Index out of range error referenced to Lvl field. So that's why I guess this is the one who blame.

The Level4 and Level5 classes inherit from Level class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are level4 and level5 on the same table?

Comment: Level4 and Level5 - different tables. But depending on Level field in TableHours table, there can exist object of Level4 or level5 type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the column `Id` and `Level`  is mapped 3 times:

- `.KeyProperty(x => x.Level)` and `.KeyProperty(x => x.LevelId, "Id");`
- `Map(x => x.Level);` and `Map(x => x.LevelId, "Id");`
- `ReferenceAny`

i would advice to remove `Map(x => x.Level);` and `Map(x => x.LevelId, "Id");` because they are duplicated with the KeyProperties

Note:

- `.Not.Insert().Not.Update()` is redundant to `.ReadOnly()` which is a shortcut for the former

Comment: Note, that Level and LevelId - are a different fields. And the ReferenceAny is a mapping for Lvl , which is also a different object than Level or LevelId

Comment: yes but `.KeyProperty(x => x.Level)` and `Map(x => x.Level)` are the same column mapped twice which results in the error. Also `TableHours.LevelId` and `TableHours.Lvl.Id` are the same too and i would remove `TableHours.LevelId` if i knew how to map referenceAny in a compositeId.

Comment: I removed mapping, except for CompositeId and ReferenceAny, and now it works! Thanks a lot!